# How to include a generated PWA manifest into a precache-manifest rendered by Workbox

Tags: webpack, workbox

I have a Webpack config file that uses a `webpack-pwa-manifest` plugin (https://github.com/arthurbergmz/webpack-pwa-manifest) to generate a PWA manifest file. The manifest file name is `manifest.hash.json`, where "hash" is a value dynamically generated on every build.

I'm also using an `InjectManifest` plugin of `Workbox` (https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-webpack-plugin) to render a precache manifest that will then gets injected into a service worker file.

Here is a "plugins" section of my Webpack config file:

```
      plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin([ path.join(destDir, '*.*') ], {
        allowExternal: true,
        exclude: [],
        verbose: true,
        dry: false
      }),
      new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        filename: 'style.[hash].css'
      }),
      new VueLoaderPlugin(),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: path.join(projectRoot, 'src/index.html')
      }),
      new WebpackPwaManifest({
        name: 'Test PWA',
        short_name: 'Test PWA',
        fingerprints: true,
        inject: true,
        lang: 'en-US',
        start_url: 'https://localhost:8120/index.html',
        display: 'standalone',
        theme_color: '#777777',
        background_color: '#333333',
        icons: [
          {
            src: path.join(sourceDir, 'images/icon.png'),
            sizes: [36, 48, 72, 96, 144, 192, 512],
            destination: 'icons'
          }
        ]
      }),
      new InjectManifest({
        swSrc: path.join(projectRoot, 'src/sw.js'),
        swDest: 'sw.js',
        importWorkboxFrom: 'local',
        globPatterns: ['dist/*.{json,js,html}']
      })
    ]
```

The problem is I cannot find a way to add a rendered `manifest.hash.json` into a precache manifest generated by InjectManifest. Is there any way to make them play nicely together or is it not possible?

Comment: If you can give the manifest a chunk name, you should be able to add the chunk of the workbox webpack plugin.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with commons chunk named `manifest.<chunkhash>.js` that wasn't included in the generated precache manifest.

The solution was to add `exclude` option to `InjectManifest` plugin in webpack config file, since the default value for it is (according to [docs](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-webpack-plugin#full_injectmanifest_config)): `[/\.map$/, /^manifest.*\.js(?:on)?$/]`.

```
plugins: [
  new InjectManifest({
    swSrc: path.join(projectRoot, 'src/sw.js'),
    swDest: 'sw.js',
    importWorkboxFrom: 'local',
    exclude: [] // <-- Add this
  })
]
```

Comment: Great find. Issue is even marked as a bug at workbox, when it's actually just a config that everyone overlooks https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/issues/1588

Answer (score 1):

It's fixed in Workbox v4.0.0: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/pull/1679

Answer (score -1):

Somehow file generated by `webpack-pwa-manifest` plugin isn't included in webpack build pipeline (maybe a bug), so `InjectManifest` plugin can't add all the assets on the fly.

There is workaround to precache additional assets using `globDirectory` and `globPatterns` options:

```
new InjectManifest({
  swSrc: './dist/sw.js',
  globDirectory: '.',
  globPatterns: ['dist/manifest.*.json']
})
```

In this config example, plugin gets all bundles and your additional manifest file as external file. But webpack gives you a warning:

> You're using the following Workbox configuration options:
>   [globDirectory, globPatterns]. In Workbox v3 and later, this is
>   usually not needed.

You should use it only to assets is that is not performed by webpack. Check the explanation in [docs](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-webpack-plugin#cache_additional_non-webpack_assets).

In your particular config the problem is that you missed `globDirectory: '.'` option and plugin can't find the file(s).

I hope it's still relevant and help you.

Comment: [WebpackInjectManifest] 'globDirectory' property is not expected to be here.